# Save a single enum value out of many types possible

Tags: java, enums

I need to make a Java class which can receive a single enum value out of many. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public enum enumA {..}
    public enum enumB {..}
    public enum enumC {..}
    public enum enumD {..}

    private OneOfTheEnumsAboveMember enumMember;
}
```

Since enums can't be extended, how can I define a single member which must be one of the enums?

Comment: Make your enums implement an interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enums cannot be extended, but they can implement interfaces. You could have an empty marker interface (or better yet - have it include methods you actually need), and make that the type of your member:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static interface EnumInterface {}
    public enum enumA implements EnumInterface {..}
    public enum enumB implements EnumInterface {..}
    public enum enumC implements EnumInterface {..}
    public enum enumD implements EnumInterface {..}

    private EnumInterface enumMember;
}
```